# How to troubleshoot sending email from Apple OS X command line (tcsh)

Tags: command-line, email, gmail

I am using the "sendmail" command in the syntax I've found on-line,

% echo "hello" | sendmail -f me@mail.com -t me@mail.com

and it gives no error but also no email gets sent. Where can I see the error that it's presumably getting, and where do I set things like the smtp info (I'll use my gmail address) so that it can actually send?

Comment: Have you looked up the syntax for `sendmail`? It seems that's likely to include the information you need.

Comment: yes; that hasn't helped me make it work.

Comment: What did you look up? Right now you've given us a blank problem but have not given us any information as to what research you've done, what other things you've tried to do to resolve things. Sending email requires an SMTP configuration of some sort. So, what does your `main.cf` file look like? Please use the EDIT button to tell us everything you've researched and tried.

Comment: I had done "man sendmail" to try to get it work but the lack of any error message made it hard to know where it was failing. However, the "mail" command worked perfectly and didn't require any extra configs.

Comment: The `man` command only brings up the manual for the command. The lack of error messages means that the specific command is not wrong and that the application is performing as it has been configured to perform, which I'm guessing is not at all. The fact that nothing happens likely means you have not configured mail on your computer yet, or not configured it in a way Sendmail requires.

Comment: yes, by "man sendmail" I meant I read the manual page on sendmail, and tried to configure it as directed, but to no effect. I was hoping to find out if there's a logfile where I could see where the process was breaking down.